# airflow: How to modify DAG to backfill?

Tags: airflow

I have a DAG has been running for a while. Now I more old data available and want to backfill.

I change my parameters:

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'drum',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2019, 7, 1),
    'retries': 2,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='dag_one',
    catchup=False,
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval='@weekly',
    max_active_runs=1
)
```

To:

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'drum',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2018, 1, 1), ### Update
    'retries': 2,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='dag_one',
    catchup=True,  ### Update
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval='@weekly',
    max_active_runs=1
)
```

However this does not trigger the backfill. I am using the GUI explicitly as I do not have access to the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

As I remember, you also need to update your `dag_id` (e. g. to `dag_one_v2`) when changing `start_date`. But be careful as updating the `dag_id` will lead to losing all dag's metadata. So Airflow will re-execute all dags since 2019-07-01. You may also need to add some kind of check, whether your data have been already processed or not.